# Using async invoke lambda or SQS/SNS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently implementing a function, where i call a other lambda like this:

```
let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let lambda = new aws.Lambda();

lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'testLambda',
    InvocationType: "Event",
    Payload: JSON.stringify(""),
}).promise();
```

This invokes my lambda async, and its very simple.

Whats the advantage if i use an SNS or SQS if this also works without writing an cloudformation/cdk for an SQS/SNS?

It also says "...lambda adds events to a queue before seinding them to your function..."

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Examples of advantages:

SNS: you can have multiple consumers of the same message.
SQS: you can have more insights into the number of pending invocations, more control over the retry behaviour.

CloudFormation / CDK: entirely unrelated here, has nothing to do with lambda invocations or SQS / SNS. It allows you to provision your infrastructure as code and automate the creation and destruction of resources.